# How to make id autoincrement in schema.prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am writing a postgreSQL database. The ID must be auto-incrementing.

```
model User {
 id            String    @id @default(cuid())
 name          String?
 email         String?   @unique
 emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
 image         String?
 createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
 updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
 posts         Post[]
 accounts      Account[]
 sessions      Session[]

 @@map(name: "users")
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miSOl.png)

If you write the ID manually, you can enter any value as in the first entry, but autocomplete generates the code as in the second entry. I got the code from the site [Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use [autoincrement](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#autoincrement) function.

Here's how it would look in `User` model:

```
model User {
 id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
 name          String?
 email         String?   @unique
 emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
 image         String?
 createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
 updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
 posts         Post[]
 accounts      Account[]
 sessions      Session[]

 @@map(name: "users")
}
```